# (Jacobson Basic Algebra I) Exercise 0.2.3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, proof-verification

Show that if there exists no maps $B_1, B_2$ of $T$ into a set $U$ such that $B_1 \neq B_2$ but $B_1\alpha = B_2\alpha$ then $\alpha : S \to T$ is surjective$.

I was having trouble with creating a direct proof of the question. So instead I proved via the contrapositive, i.e. suppose that $\alpha$ is not surjective we can find $B_1$ and $B_2$ as desired. Let $U = \{0,1,2\}$. Then since $\alpha$ is not surjective denote $T'$ as the set of elements in $T$ that are not mapped to by $\alpha$ (we also know that this set is empty). Then let $B_1(x) = 0$ if $x \in a(S)$ and $1$ if $x\in T'$. Similarly, $B_2(x) = 0$ if $x \in a(S)$ and $2$ if $x \in T'$. Do these functions complete the proof or am I missing something?

I would also appreciate hints on how to go about a direct proof or proof by contradicition.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha:S\to T$ is not surjective. Then there is $t\in T$ such that, $t\not=\alpha(s)$ for any $s\in S$.

Let $B_1:T\to\{0,1\}$ and $B_2:T\to\{0,1\}$ defined by $B_1(\alpha(s))=0=B_2(\alpha(s))$ for all $s\in S$ with $B_1(t')=0,B_2(t')=1$ for all $t'\in T-\text{im}(\alpha)$.

Then by definition $B_1\not=B_2$ but $B_1\alpha=B_2\alpha$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: You should take $B_1(t')=0=B_2(t')$ for all $t'\in T-\{t\}$.

Comment: @AndrewHubery    why? I have edited.

Comment: You need $B_i$ to be defined on all of $T$, not just on the image of $\alpha$.

Comment: I have already done this